# Como abrir uma <div> ao clicar em um link <a>?

Tags: jquery

> Estou criando um elemento para um site pessoal, e gostaria que esse elemento "`<div>`" seja aberto/fechado quando for clicado em um botão.

É uma `<div>` contendo algumas bandeiras de países para mudar o idioma.

Acho que poderia ser usado aquela função `.slide` do jQuery pra criar esse efeito.

Porém, sei apenas o básico em jQuery.

Obrigado desde já :)

Obs:
A div a ser aberta é essa:

```
<div id="paises">Aqui ficará as bandeiras</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para apresentar ou esconder um elemento com base no clique de outro vamos precisar de usar dois métodos:

- jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) para executar código quando o botão recebe um clique.
- jQuery [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) para animar o elemento alvo e alternar a sua apresentação entre "escondido" e "visível".

Ver exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/77dm6gk8/).

```js
$('button').on("click", function() {
  $('div').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Tens bandeiras?</button>
<div>Tenho, bué da bandeiras, mas é assim, não sei onde meti os icons e então acabei por escrever um texto muito longo a dar conta que não sabia dos icons e nem sei se todos estão a ler isto até ao fim? Tu estás? É pá! Bora lá bater um papo...</div>
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu buscava! Obrigado. Agora vou só mudar esse `<button>` e esse `<div>` que você não colocou o id. Mas ficou excelente!

Comment: como faço para mudar a velocidade do `.slide` ?

Comment: Para ficar lento: `.slideToggle("slow")`, ou para ficar muito lento: `.slideToggle(10000)` ou para rebentar com o navegador: `.slideToggle(100000000)`!

Comment: Para ficar rápido: `.slideToggle("fast")` ou `.slideToggle(200)`!

Answer (score 5):

Não é necessário o uso de Javascript na maioria dos casos em que é preciso fazer algum tipo de *toggle* em outro elemento. Basta um `<input>` de tipo [*checkbox*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) para fazer o controle de quando mostrar ou esconder, então nas folhas de estilos pode se utilizar a pseudo-classe [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) para criar regras dependendo do estado do *input*.

```css
/* Escondendo a caixinha de marcação e o div alvo. */
div, input{ 
  display: none
}

/* Texto exibido quando o checkbox não estiver marcado. */
input + label::before {
  content: 'Mostrar '
}

/* Texto exibido quando o checkbox estiver marcado. */
input:checked + label:before {
  content: 'Esconder '
}

/* Exibe o elemento de ID 'bandeiras' quando o checkbox estiver marcado. */
input:checked ~ #bandeiras {
  display: block
}


img { width: 300px }
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='toggle'>
<label for='toggle'>Bandeiras</label>

<div id='bandeiras'>
  <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAGPC.png' alt='Klingons'>
</div>
```

Evidentemente isto precisa de uma aparência melhor, porém foquei somente na questão do comportamento que foi perguntado ignorando que o click deveria ocorrer em um elemento âncora.

Questões como animações e transições suaves podem ser resolvidas facilmente com as propriedades [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation) e [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transition) das CSS.

---

> <sub>A regra `img { width: 300px }` foi usada somente p/ limitar o tamanho da imagem, não tem importância para a técnica do *checkbox*.</sub>

Comment: Que legal! #RealizandoTestes :)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) e um pouco de CSS, exemplo:

```js
function abreFecha(sel) {
  $(sel).slideToggle();
}
```

```css
#paises {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:abreFecha('#paises')">Clique em mim</a>

<div id="paises">Bandeiras aqui</div>
```

Comment: Mas, e o efeito? Não é bem como eu quero... Não imagino assim. :/

Comment: @AlexandreLopes atualizei a resposta com o `.slideToggle()` do jQuery.

Comment: Seria possível não utilizar `javascript:` no `<a>`? Está ficando perfeito! :)

Comment: O que dispara o toggle é a função `abreFecha()`. No exemplo acima usei no próprio link, mas sinta-se livre para usar onde achar melhor. ;)

Comment: Vou fazer algumas alterações, é legal essa parte do <a>, obrigado por contribuir ;)

Answer (score 3):

esse link tem um exemplo que vai ajudar 
http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/menu-responsivo-em-slider-lateral.php

Mais por alto, você pode pegar o evento de click do seu button via js e usar o id da sua div no document.querySelector() do js ou no $() do jquery pra acessar os atributos da div e mecher no css dela adicionando ou retirando display:none ou um visibility:hidden dependendo de como quer manter o layout por exemplo...

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! :)