# Exibir Div com conteúdo específico ao clicar em link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Bom dia pessoal, estou criando esse tópico pois realizei uma busca no fórum e encontrei essa solução aqui.

[Como abrir uma <div> ao clicar em um link <a>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44717/como-abrir-uma-div-ao-clicar-em-um-link-a?rq=1)

Porém eu preciso de uma solução mais específica.

Estou desenvolvendo um questionário, para cada questão, eu criei uma tag  AJUDA 
Essa tag deve exibir uma div ao ser clicada (até aí, está tudo certo)

Problema:

Para cada tag  AJUDA  eu preciso exibir um conteúdo específico. Ou seja, se o link for clicado na questão um, a div ao lado deve ser aberta mas com o conteúdo específico para ajudar na questão 1, se o link  for clicado na questão dois, o conteúdo a ser exibido deve ser referente a questão dois.. e assim por diante.

Minha solução:

Eu posso criar N DIVs com um seletor ID com o conteúdo específico para cada tag  . Mas eu gostaria de simplificar esse processo, algo como: utilizar uma class para identificar a div e comparar qual Link foi clicado para exibir o elemento específico dentro dessa div, aí eu usaria a mesma div sempre, apenas com o conteúdo distinto...

Acho que é isso pessoal, não sei se ficou muito claro.

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Como está seu código?

Comment: Poste o que você já tem.

Answer (score 2):

na verdade não sei se era isso que queria, mas pelo que entendi fiz esse código para te explicar.

**HTML**

```
<button id="tag1">TAG1</button>
<button id="tag2">TAG2</button>

<div id="tagContent"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{

display:none;

}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('button').on("click", function() {
        switch($(this).attr('id')) {
    case 'tag1':
        var conteudo = 'conteudo 1';
        break;
    case 'tag2':
        var conteudo = 'conteudo 2';
        break;
        }
    $('div').text(conteudo);
    $('div').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Minha abordagem utiliza um elemento oculto dentro do próprio link, que ao ser clicado copia o conteúdo html dele para a div de apresentação.

Creio que dessa forma fica mais fácil a edição dos conteúdos, principalmente se forem muitos links, e com conteúdos dinâmicos vindos do banco de dados.

Recomendo que toda a parte de conteúdos fique sempre inteiramente no html, e o script faça apenas a manipulação necessária.

```js
$('a.link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('div.content').html($('div', this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 1<div style="display:none">Conteudo do link 1</div></a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 2<div style="display:none">Conteudo do link 2</div></a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 3<div style="display:none">Conteudo do link 3</div></a>
<div class="content"></div>
```