# Html + Css criação de perguntas frequentes

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Boa Tarde,
Comecei a pouco tempo a evoluir o meu html+css para a criação de páginas web será que alguém me pode dar uma dica de como fazer o que é pedido na imagem a baixo?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Basicamente quando clicamos na área onde tem a seta no canto direito a programação faz com que apareça uma caixa por baixo com texto e clicando de novo ela desaparece. Como uma caixa escondida que só aparece quando clicamos na pergunta e aparece a resposta.

Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: não deu pra entender... seja mais claro por favor

Comment: Veja se percebe assim

Comment: Você está procurando por um Accordion. Veja se é isso mesmo e adicione a sua pergunta, ficará mais fácil de compreende-la assim

Comment: Um exemplo com Sass e HTML apenas: https://codepen.io/abergin/pen/ihlDf

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar a mesma técnica [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44726/4808) e criar um efeito de "*toggle*" somente com HTML e CSS:

```css
.question {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0
}

.question input,
.question .answer { display: none }

.question label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%
}

.question input:checked ~ .answer {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class='question'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='question-1'>
  <label for='question-1'>Primeira pergunta?</label>
  <div class='answer'>
    Primeira resposta.
  </div>
</div>

<div class='question'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='question-2'>
  <label for='question-2'>Segunda pergunta?</label>
  <div class='answer'>
    Segunda resposta.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que se entendi sua pergunta, vou te passar umas referencias. Aconselho o bootstrap, pois se esta iniciando ainda, aconselho pegar algo pronto para depois arriscar a fazer do zero. Segue link das referencias e o código abaixo. Espero ter ajduado!!
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_accordion&stacked=h

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O comportamento ao qual você se refere, chama-se accordion ou collapse.

Veja um exemplo do collapse com **Bootstrap**: http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Você pode fazer isso na **mão**, veja esse exemplo:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

**Html**

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
}

div.panel.show {
    display: block;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795'; 
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796";
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```